# What are the distinctive features of ISL and PPL for ClooG when using gcc?

Tags: gcc, optimization, ppl, cloog, isl

When building or using any given version of `gcc`, why I should prefer 1 of this 2 backends for ClooG over the other ?

I can't find a good documentation about it on the `gcc` website .

Comment: IIRC, it depends upon the version of GCC. Some prefer ISL others prefer PPL ...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch 1) with "others" you mean "other people" or "on some versions of gcc ISL works better then PPL and viceversa" 2) I still don't have a good idea idea about what are the implications as far as `gcc` is concerned, I basically have a little to nil idea of what this 2 things do. I know that are somehow optimizing loops and the dataflow, but I still don't have enough informations to tell what they really do or determine which one I should choose .

Comment: I thought each version of gcc only worked with one of those.

Answer (score 1):

You want to read this: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Graphite-4.8

Basically, you cannot really choose. All newer version of GCC (>= 4.8) use CLooG with ISL. Older versions have a PPL backend.